# How to filter an ArrayList with "Male" and "Female" in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, filter

I have an arraylist that goes in to a list, I want to allow users to filter it by male and female, I know how to filter lists, I have applied the filter with date, however as both male and female contain male, I am quite confused how to approach this.

Could someone please guide me, I've no code to show as as I can't get my head around it - seems logic isn't my thing!

Comment: You need to filter a list of String, right?

Comment: "I've no code to show" ... "I have an arraylist that goes in to a list" - show us that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to filter the list of string - you can use `Stream` to do so.

```
List<String> strings =
            Arrays.asList("male", "female", "male", "female","lorem","ipsum");
```

Let's get only "male" `String`:

```
List<String> male = strings.stream().
             filter("male"::equalsIgnoreCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
// will contain ["male","male"]
```

Female only will be similar:

```
List<String> female = strings.stream().
                    filter("female"::equalsIgnoreCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
// ["female","female","female"]
```

And finally both female and male

```
List<String> femaleAndMale = strings.stream().
       filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("male") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("female"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `.equals()` since they both contain `"male"`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("male","female", "female", "male"));                                      
    System.out.println("List Before filtering \"male\": " + list);
    for (Iterator<String> it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      if (!it.next().equals("male")) {//Change to .equals("female") to filter female
        it.remove();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("List After filtering \"male\": " + list);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
List Before filtering "male": [male, female, female, male]
List After filtering "male": [male, male]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/F5V3/2)

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` function.**

> This functions are the correct way for comparing **full** strings.

So if you set something like this:

`myString.equals("male")` and `myString` contains only the `String` "**male**" then is the only possible way this will return `true`.

> if you compare using `==` you will endup comparing memory references,
>   that is exactly what you don't want here